# UNION ALL and Nulls / Error

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, union-all

I am working on a UNION ALL and receive this error to start:

Msg 205, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
All queries combined using a UNION, INTERSECT or EXCEPT operator must have an equal number of expressions in their target lists.

This is where I believe the error occurs:

```
With CTE AS(
SELECT Pull_Date, Well_Name, Part1 Part, Part1_PN PartPN, Part1_SN PartSN FROM testtest
UNION ALL
    SELECT Pull_Date, Well_Name, Part2, Part2_PN, Part2_SN, Part3, Part3_PN, Part3_SN from testtest
)
```

I believe I need to insert more fields in the first SELECT statement.  I have corrected it with the below work, but when I do this I am not receiving some of the information I need from Part3, Part4, and I would suspect the 15 other parts I would need to input.  When I look for AGH (which is not in part1 or part2 but is in part3) I only receive NULL information.  So AGH, AGH_PN, AGH_SN are all NULL when I am expecting some information to be in there.

```
    With CTE AS(
SELECT Pull_Date, Well_Name, Part1 Part, Part1_PN PartPN, Part1_SN PartSN, NULL t1, NULL t2, NULL t3, NULL t4, NULL t5, NULL t6 FROM testtest
UNION ALL
    SELECT Pull_Date, Well_Name, Part2, Part2_PN, Part2_SN, Part3, Part3_PN, Part3_SN, Part4, Part4_PN, Part4_SN from testtest
)

Select Pull_Date, Well_Name,
    MIN(CASE WHEN Part='BODH' THEN 'BODH' ELSE NULL END) [BODH],
    MIN(CASE WHEN Part='BODH' THEN PartPN Else NULL END) BODH_PN,
    MIN(CASE WHEN Part='BODH' THEN PartSN ELSE NULL END) BODH_SN,
    MIN(CASE WHEN Part='Cable' THEN 'Cable' ELSE NULL END) [Cable],
    MIN(CASE WHEN Part= 'Cable' THEN PartPN Else NULL END) Cable_PN,
    MIN(CASE WHEN Part= 'Cable' THEN PartSN ELSE NULL END) Cable_SN,
    MIN(CASE WHEN Part= 'Pump' THEN 'Pump' ELSE Null END) [Pump],
    MIN(CASE WHEN Part= 'Pump' THEN PartPN ELSE NULL END) Pump_PN,
    MIN(CASE WHEN Part= 'Pump' THEN PartSN ELSE NULL END) Pump_SN,
    MIN(CASE WHEN Part= 'MLE' THEN 'MLE' ELSE NULL END) [MLE],
    MIN(CASE WHEN Part= 'MLE' THEN PartPN ELSE NULL END) MLE_PN,
    MIN(CASE WHEN Part= 'MLE' THEN PartSN ELSE NULL END) MLE_SN,
    MIN(CASE WHEN Part= 'AGH' THEN 'AGH' ELSE NULL END) [AGH],
    MIN(CASE WHEN Part= 'AGH' THEN PartPN ELSE NULL END) AGH_PN,
    MIN(CASE WHEN Part= 'AGH' THEN PartSN ELSE NULL END) AGH_SN
FROM CTE
GROUP BY Pull_Date, Well_Name
```

Any assistance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I see, why are you adding Part3 in the second query? I'd think you want something more like this:

```
With CTE AS
(
  SELECT Pull_Date, Well_Name, Part1 AS Part, Part1_PN AS PartPN, Part1_SN AS PartSN FROM testtest
UNION ALL
  SELECT Pull_Date, Well_Name, Part2, Part2_PN, Part2_SN FROM testtest
UNION ALL
  SELECT Pull_Date, Well_Name, Part3, Part3_PN, Part3_SN FROM testtest
)
```

Is there perhaps more to this set-up than what your question reveals? What does your table look like?

You stated that your problem is that AGH is always returning nulls and is populated in the "Part3" fields. If this is the case, you'll need to pull in that data for the "Part3" fields the same way you did for parts 1 and 2.

When you're aggregating data from multiple fields like this, you'll want to make sure each instance is its own record. Breaking Part3 out like you did with Part2 and Part1 ... allows you to get rid of the additional fields (NULL t1, NULL t2, etc...) and keeps your similar data fields in the same context.

Comment: Paurian, thank you this looks to be what I am looking for.  I just blanked out being able to UNION ALL another select statement.  I made the changes you suggested and it pulled the AGH information I was looking for.  Thanks again for the help.

Comment: Always a pleasure to help out! Thanks for posting enough details in your question that I was able to do so.

Answer (score 0):

You're right, the error is in the query you highlighted. The error message is telling you that the number of fields that you return from the queries either side of the UNION ALL should be the same, otherwise it does not know how to combine them into a single resultset

Answer (score 0):

```html
-- This SELECT statement has five columns.  The last three are aliased. 
SELECT Pull_Date, Well_Name, Part1 Part, Part1_PN PartPN, Part1_SN PartSN FROM testtest
UNION ALL
-- This SELECT statement has eight columns.  Hence the error. 
SELECT Pull_Date, Well_Name, Part2, Part2_PN, Part2_SN, Part3, Part3_PN, Part3_SN from testtest
```

So either there needs to be commas in the first SELECT because the alias names are actually column names and the absense of a comma is a typo, or you need to eyeball the second SELECT so it aligns with the first, or if the second SELECT is correct and there are eight columns then the first SELECT needs to include 'placeholder' columns like , NULL as Part, so that both SELECTs have eight columns.

Comment: Jim, I must apologize I did have the commas added in the original but did not add it in this one thus resulting in this typo.  Thank you for your help.